# How send attributes with has_many relation in active admin form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have form, when i submit this form rails redirect to `new_admin_item_path` with params, but i need add to `app_f.input :gost, as: :select` selected option how i can do it?

This is my form.

```
form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
    f.inputs "Item" do
      f.input :name, label: 'Имя', :input_html => { :value => params[:name] } 
      f.input :category_id, as: :select, collection: SubCategory.all, :selected => params[:category_id]
      f.input :size
      f.input :wall_th, label: "Толщина стенки"
      f.input :price, :input_html => { :value => params[:price] } 
    end
    f.inputs do
    f.has_many :item_gosts, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |app_f|
      if !app_f.object.nil?
        # show the destroy checkbox only if it is an existing appointment
        # else, there's already dynamic JS to add / remove new appointments
        app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
      end
      app_f.input :gost, as: :select, collection: if params[:id].present?
        Item.find(params[:id]).sub_category.gosts.all
      else
        Gost.all
      end

      #app_f.input :item_gosts # it should automatically generate a drop-down select to choose from your existing patients
    end
    f.has_many :item_steel_marks, allow_destroy: true, new_record: true do |app_f|
      if !app_f.object.nil?
        # show the destroy checkbox only if it is an existing appointment
        # else, there's already dynamic JS to add / remove new appointments
        app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?"
      end
      app_f.input :steel_mark, as: :select, collection: if params[:id].present?
        Item.find(params[:id]).sub_category.steel_marks.all
      else
        SteelMark.all
      end
  end
  f.input :description, :input_html => { :value => params[:description] } 
end
    f.button "Сохранить"
  end
```

This is active admin cotroller.

```
controller do

    def new
      @item = Item.new
    end

    def create
      @item = Item.create(item_params)
      if @item.save
        flash[:success] = "Товар добавлен"
        redirect_to new_admin_item_path(:category_id => @item.category_id, :name => @item.name, price: @item.price, description: @item.description)
      else
         flash[:alert] = "ошибка"
         render 'new'
      end
    end
```

Comment: да, форма рабочая, не могу никак сделать чтобы при создании следующего Item были выбраны :gost из предыдущего Item

Comment: I think, it's another question, if you create new one, i can take a look when ill be near comp

Answer (score 1):

[Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) (which is used in AA) [has deprecated `selected` option](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Deprecation-of-:selected-option).

You can use `options_for_select`.

Take a look at example:

```
collection: options_for_select([1,2,3], 2) # will make 2 a default value
```

So in your case you can try:

```
 app_f.input :gost,
   as: :select,
   collection: options_for_select( (params[:id].present? ? Item.find(params[:id]).sub_category.gosts.all : Gost.all), Gost.first) # will make `Gost.first` a default value.
```

For sure `Gost.first` in this case is just an example of defining a default value, and you have to work out something which is really meets your requirements.

This part `(params[:id].present? ? Item.find(params[:id]).sub_category.gosts.all : Gost.all)` uses `ternary` operator and is a bit shorter (but still does the same) as your `if else` statement.